# Find names of the functions defined in a file

Tags: functions

Lets say I have a file named `file.m` that contains:

```
test[] := (
  Print["test"]
)
```

How would I go about extracting the function declarations in such a file consistently as a list?

I have figured out how to extract the data without having it execute.

```
Import["file.m", "Text"]
```

This is my current code.

```
Cases[
 FullForm[
  MakeExpression[Import["file.m", "Text"], TraditionalForm]
  ],
 SetDelayed[x__, y__] -> f[x, y]
 ]
```

Comment: Does `ToHeldExpression@Import["file.m", "Text"]` satisfy your needs? You can get rid of the `Null`s in a post-processing step.

Comment: @rm-rf How do I insure I only get function declarations for example lets say the file has a `Print["test"]` at the end of the file?

Comment: I'm not sure that's an easy task or if it can be done in a foolproof manner, given the myriad of ways in which a function can be "defined" in _Mathematica_...

Comment: @rm-rf Okay lets just assume a convention is followed and all functions are declared as `:=` (`SetDelayed`)

Comment: Well, then why not do something like you did in your question? ;) `Cases[ToHeldExpression@Import["~/file.m", "Text"], 
 x_SetDelayed :> Hold@x]` (use `Unevaluated` or `Defer` or `Hold` as per your needs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Preamble

This is not such an easy task actually, if you want to do this fast and clean. I have been developing some functionality for one of my side projects, for which I needed to analyze symbols inside packages, so I will share some of the code I ended up with.

### Speed

The following function will be two orders of magnitude faster than the one based on `Import[...,"HeldExpressions"]`:

```
ClearAll[loadFile];
loadFile[path_String?FileExistsQ]:=
    DeleteCases[            
        ToExpression[
            FromCharacterCode[BinaryReadList[path]],InputForm,HoldComplete
        ],
        Null
    ]
```

hopefully this function is still robust enough.

#### Benchmarks

Benchmarks on a medium-size package:

```
file = FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory,"SystemFiles","Links","JLink", "JLink.m"}];

Do[Import[file, "HeldExpressions"], {100}] // AbsoluteTiming
Do[loadFile[file], {100}] // AbsoluteTiming

(*

  {4.351563, Null}
  {0.153320, Null}
*)
```

The format of the result of `loadFile` is a little different - it just wraps all code in one `HoldComplete`. But it is easy to transform to the partial `HoldComplete` wrapped around the pieces.

The speed difference can be quite important (for my application it was. I would have been in trouble using `Import`).

### Namespace pollution

#### The problem

Perhaps even worse than the speed issue is the one of namespace pollution, which is a flaw shared by both methods described so far. The new symbols are being created as a result of parsing the code, and they are created in whatever happens to be the current working context. For example, for the case at hand:

```
Names["Global`*`*"]//Short

(* 
  {Global`Private`arg,Global`Private`arg$,Global`Private`e,
  <<21>>,Global`Private`val,Global`Private`val$,Global`Package`$jlinkDir}
*)
```

#### Sugegsted solution

With the implementation details described at the bottom of the post, here is the way I ended up doing this: I introduced the macro with the following signature:

```
withHeldCodeInTemporaryContext[{var_Symbol, code_}, fname_, opts : OptionsPattern[]]
```

which is supposed to read in the file `fname`, parse it into some temporary context, assign the result to a variable `var`, then execute the code `code`, and finally clean up that temporary context. Here is an example of use (you will need to run the code posted below for it to work):

```
Block[
{       
   heldCode,
   file=
      FileNameJoin[
         {$InstallationDirectory,"SystemFiles","Links","JLink","JLink.m"}
      ]
},
   withHeldCodeInTemporaryContext[          
      {             
         heldCode,
         Union[
            Cases[heldCode,s_Symbol:>ToString[Unevaluated[s]],\[Infinity],Heads->True]
         ]
      },
      file
   ]
]
```

This code collects all the symbols which build up the code being read. The result looks like:

```
(*
  {And,AppendTo,BeginPackage,Blank,Check,Close,  
  <<78>>,$ContextPath,$Failed,$Input,$Off,$SystemID,$VersionNumber}
*)
```

but one can check that the working context (or any other context) was not polluted.

#### Implementation

Here is the code (formatting done using the [code formatter palette](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/code-formatting-automation-for-our-posts/1026#1026)):

```
SetAttributes[CleanUp,HoldAll];
CleanUp[expr_,cleanup_]:=
   Module[{exprFn,result,abort=False,rethrow=True,seq},          
      exprFn[]:=
         expr;
      result=
         CheckAbort[                
            Catch[Catch[result=exprFn[];rethrow=False;result],_,seq[##1]&],
            abort=True
         ];
      cleanup;
      If[abort,Abort[]];
      If[rethrow,Throw[result/. 
         seq->Sequence]];
      result
   ]

SetAttributes[parseInContext,HoldFirst];    
Options[parseInContext]=
   {          
      LocalizingContext->"MyLocalizingContext`",
      DefaultImportedContexts:>{},
      ExtraImportedContexts:>{}
   };    
parseInContext[code_,opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=
   Module[
   {          
      result,
      context=OptionValue[LocalizingContext],
      defcontexts=OptionValue[DefaultImportedContexts],
      extraContexts=OptionValue[ExtraImportedContexts],
      allContexts
   },          
      allContexts={Sequence@@defcontexts,Sequence@@extraContexts};          
      Block[{$ContextPath},             
         CleanUp[                
            BeginPackage[context];Needs/@allContexts;result=code,
            EndPackage[]
         ];
         result
      ]
   ];


ClearAll[inPrivateContext];
SetAttributes[inPrivateContext,HoldAll];
inPrivateContext[code_]:=
   CleanUp[Begin["`Private`"];code,End[]];


ClearAll[parseInPrivateSubcontext];
SetAttributes[parseInPrivateSubcontext,HoldFirst];
parseInPrivateSubcontext[code_,opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=
   parseInContext[inPrivateContext[code],opts];


ClearAll[withTemporaryContext];
SetAttributes[withTemporaryContext,HoldRest];
withTemporaryContext[context_String,{contVar_Symbol,code_}]:=
   Block[{contVar=context},
      With[{names=context<>"Private`*",remove=If[Names[#1]=!={},Remove[#1]]&},
         CleanUp[remove[names];code,remove[names]]
      ]
   ];


ClearAll[withHeldCodeInTemporaryContext];
Options[withHeldCodeInTemporaryContext]=
   {          
      TemporaryContextName->"TemporaryContext`",
      ExtraImportedContexts:>{"Global`"}
   };
SetAttributes[withHeldCodeInTemporaryContext,HoldFirst];    
withHeldCodeInTemporaryContext[
   {var_Symbol,code_},fname_,opts:OptionsPattern[]
]:=
   Module[{tempcont},
      Block[{var},
         withTemporaryContext[                
            OptionValue[TemporaryContextName],
            {                   
               tempcont,
               parseInPrivateSubcontext[                      
                  var=loadFile[fname];code,
                  LocalizingContext->tempcont,
                  ExtraImportedContexts->OptionValue[ExtraImportedContexts]
               ]
            }
         ]
      ]
   ];
```

The code contains a number of macros,some of which are general (like WReach's `CleanUp` and a few others), while others specialize the generic ones to the more narrow goals we set here.

Comment: Well thought out.  How does `loadFile["testing.m"]` pollute the namespace in my example code above?  I tried running `loadFile["testing.m"]` then `test[]` but I get no output.  Am I misunderstanding you or maybe I misunderstand how namespaces work.

Comment: @Liam In your case, the only non-system symbol you have is `test`, and you use it anyway. To get the output, you need to use `ReleaseHold`, since the result of `loadFile` is code wrapped in `HoldComplete`. In more complicated cases, where you may have many non-system symbols in your file, all of them will be created in the current working context, unless fully-qualified names were used for them (which is not typical). Generally, such namespace pollution is not what one wants.

Comment: How might you extract the functions from notebook `.nb` file?

Comment: @Liam [This question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/compile-for-deployment) can be a good start.

Comment: Do you mind modifying your example such that it writes to a file or produce some type of output it's not clear to me what form `HeldCode` (maybe `HoldForm` or `HoldComplete`) should be in.  I have attempted to construct a working example here http://pastebin.com/PdqU9XB8

Comment: @Liam I looked through your pastebin code, but it is still not clear to me what you want to achieve. Perhaps let me explain how `withHeldCodeInTemporaryContext` works. The variable `heldCode` you don't have to assign anything. It gets automatically assigned to the code of the file you read by `withHeldCodeInTemporaryContext`, parsed in a temporary context, and wrapped in `Hold`. For example, you could call `withHeldCodeInTemporaryContext[{helodCode,Print[heldCode]}, "code.m"]` to print the parsed held content of your file. The point is, `withHeldCodeInTemporaryContext` is a scoping construct..

Comment: @Liam ... (`Block`-like), and it allows you to access the parsed code in the `code` parameter, becuase you can use `heldCode` (or whatever other name you give to this variable) inside `code`. In particular, if you execute `withHeldCodeInTemporaryContext[{myHeldCode, ReleaseHold@myHeldCode},"code.m"]`, you will effectively execute the (parsed into a temporary context) code of your package.  But if you want to access some of the functions of this file by their short name, this will need more work, since `withHeldCodeInTemporaryContext` will not easily allow that (but this can be done).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I now understand how to properly execute your code.  Now, I don't understand enough of how it works to be certain but I believe this answer delivers similar functionality http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29779#29785 Here is a simpler example http://pastebin.com/VpjrGEzg .  Now again I'm not entirely but thought it might help you

Comment: @Liam Sorry, really no time at the moment to look further into this. Ping me in a week or so here, if you still have a problem with this then.

Comment: Your code works fine as is.  I don't need you to look further into it ;) I was just linking to another question for documentation purposes.  I thought it might help you simplify the code.

Comment: @Liam Ok, I see now. My code was originally intended to do something a little different from what is in that answer you linked. It could be used here, but the linked answer is perhaps more direct specifically for your problem, I agree. OTOH, I tried to avoid direct modifications of `$ContextPath` and `$Context` by using higher-level functions `Begin`, `End`, `BeginPackage` and `EndPackage` - which made my code a little more complex, but this was a  deliberate design choice.

Answer (score 7):

The `"HeldExpressions"` element for [package import](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/Package.html) should be useful:

```
In[4]:= Import["foo.m", "HeldExpressions"]

Out[4]= {HoldComplete[test[] := Print["test"]]}
```

Comment: Nice! I had not seen this before.

Comment: @rm-rf definitely a useful addition to your toolkit.

Answer (score 2):

This answer starts with Brett Champion's excellent idea for importing a `.m` file, but follows through to produce the list of defined functions according the relaxed criterion of finding only the names of functions defined with `SetDelay`.

```
testData = Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen", "*.m"], "HeldExpressions"];
Union @ Cases[testData, HoldPattern[SetDelayed[f_[___], _]] -> f, ∞]
```

The reason for using `Union` is to suppress multiple occurrences of the names of functions with multiple definitions.

To test this, I evaluated the first expression, and when the file open dialog appeared I chose `Turtle.m`, a turtle graphics package I wrote some years ago. The evaluation resulted in `testData` being bound to a list of the package's expressions, all wrapped with `HoldComplete`. Evaluating the second expression gave

> ```
> {
>   bk, distXY, extend, fd, goXY, heading, home, isPenDown, isPenUp,  
>   isTurtle, isValid, lf, new, pd, place, pu, rt, setH, setPen, setXY,  
>   toward, track, trackFilter
> }
> ```

This is a complete list of the turtle graphics functions defined in `Turtle.m`.