# How can I temporarily suspend the Combinatorica package?

Tags: packages, combinatorica

Sometimes after I load the Combinatorica package by entering `` Needs["Combinatorica`"] ``, I need to use *Mathematica* for something like:

```
PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{Range[10]}]}] // GroupElements.
```

I get this message:

> GroupElements::perm: Cycles[{{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}}] is not a valid permutation. >> GroupElements::argr: GroupElements called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected. >>.

In other words, it doesn't work!

Is there a way to temporarily suspend the Combinatorica package.  Right now I have to shut down *Mathematica* and restart it.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37674/creating-a-custom-context-with-a-hold-construct (hat-tip Oleksandr)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll want to manipulate `$ContextPath`. The following will do:

```
removeCombinatorica[] := (
 oldContextPath = $ContextPath;
 $ContextPath = DeleteCases[$ContextPath, "Combinatorica`"];
)

readdCombinatorica[] := ($ContextPath = oldContextPath;)
```

Then you can call `removeCombinatorica[]` before whatever you want to ignore Combinatorica, and `readdCombinatorica[]` after you've done it.