# Language`* documentation project

Tags: syntax, documentation, undocumented

`` Language` `` context is around for a long time. It is also heavily used (APIFunctions / FormFunctions dependencies deployment rely on it).

It is undocumented and while I understand WRI won't support it just because we know how to use it, it will be very handy to have clear usage descriptions of:

```
? Language`*
```

[image]

Feel free to add/edit exsiting answers, they are based on our experience rather than internal knowledge so they may not be accurate.

#### Index:

- [**`` `*Definition* ``**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/165915/5478)

  - `` `DefinitionList ``
  - `` `ExtendedDefinition ``
  - `` `ExtendedFullDefinition ``
- [**`` `*Mutation* ``**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/165910/5478)

  - `` `SetMutationHandler ``
  - `` `HasMutationHandlerQ ``
  - `` `HandleMutation ``
  - `` `MutationFallthrough ``
- [`` `*ExpressionStore* ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171154/5478)

  - `` `NewExpressionStore ``
  - `` `ExpressionStore ``

#### TODO:

```
{ `ArrayObject, `DestructureLValue, `FromArrayObject
, `FromVariableLengthInteger,  `FullGet, `GetLValueSymbol
, `InactivateExclusionsDefault, `LinkCombine, `NewArrayObject
, `PropertyItemMap, `TimeVariableLengthInteger
, `ToVariableLengthInteger, `UpdateInactivateExclusions
}
```

Comment: To be clear, is the question "what do the functions in ``Language`*`` do"?

Comment: @quantumdot yes

Comment: Will a more ambitious project be possible to document all the undocumented functions?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ It would be hard to find motivation knowing that the answer is somewhere at WRIs desks anyway. So we end up cracking stuff we need or find interesting. You can always start such project, maybe on github because it may be too broad here.

Comment: This question is a bit version-dependent. For example, in v12 there are no symbols called `ArrayObject`, `NewArrayObject`, and `FromArrayObject`, because they are replaced with the official and documented `NumericArray` and `Normal@NumericArray`.

Comment: ```Language`*VariableLengthInteger``` functions allow one to convert an arbitrary integer to a short byte sequence and vice versa. This encoding method is used in WXF file format and described in the section `Length Encoding (Varint)` of https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WXFFormatDescription.html

Answer (score 20):

## Language`*Mutation*

*First seen [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141916/38205), implemented by Taliesin Beynon*

### What do they do?

The only functions I really know about in this bunch are the `` ?Language`*Mutation* `` functions.

This is an interface that allows you to build things that work like `CloudExpression`. For example, I can make a `CloudExpression` and use `AppendTo` on it:

```
ce = CreateCloudExpression[<||>]

(* ==> CloudExpression[...]*)

AppendTo[ce, 1 -> 2]

(* ==> CloudExpression[...] *)
```

This is really implemented at the `UpValues` level, but for many things the expression itself might be too deep to use via `UpValues`, e.g.:

```
ce[[1]] = 4

(* ==> 4*)
```

For this they use `` Language`SetMutationHandler `` to handle what would otherwise have been a failed assignment:

```
obj["uuid"][[1]] = 2

(* > Set::setps: obj[uuid] in the part assignment is not a symbol. *)

(* ==> 2*)
```

And there are a bunch of symbols these days that use this:

```
ToExpression[
  Names["*`*"]
, StandardForm
, Function[Null, If[Language`HasMutationHandlerQ[#], #, Nothing], HoldFirst]
]

(*{Audio`AudioGraph, AudioStream, CloudExpression, EntityStore, 
 InitializationValue, PersistentObject, PersistentValue}*)
```

### Language`SetMutationHandler

This is the heart of the interface. We call it like:

```
Language`SetMutationHandler[type, handler]
```

which registers a mutation handler for `type`. `CloudExpression` for instance has the handler `` CloudExpression`PackageScope`CloudExpressionMutate ``.

Here's a concrete example of this in action:

```
oop`mut~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete
oop`mut[Set[f_[oop`ob[s_], p___], v_]] := Set[f[s, p], v]

sym = {1, 2};
oop`ob[sym][[1]] = 2
sym

(*Set::setps: oop`ob[sym] in the part assignment is not a symbol.*)

(* ==> 2 *)
(* ==> {1, 2} *)

Language`SetMutationHandler[oop`ob, oop`mut]

oop`ob[sym][[1]] = 2
sym

(* ==> 2 *)
(* ==> {2, 2} *)
```

### Language`HasMutationHandlerQ

Pretty clear from the previous section

### Language`HandleMutation

This is how the `MutationHandler` system does its dirty work. For example:

```
Language`HandleMutation[oop`ob[sym][[1]] = 2]

(* Set::noval: Symbol sym in part assignment does not have an immediate value. *)

(* ==> HoldComplete[1] *)
```

One thing to note, if the `Handler` doesn't do anything, the system will keep trying to mutate it until it bottoms out:

```
Language`SetMutationHandler[oop`ob, oop`mut2]
Language`HandleMutation[oop`ob[sym][[1]] = 2]

(* oop`ob::mutreclim: Too many nested mutations occurred. *)

(* oop`ob::modfl: The modification oop`ob[sym][[1]]=2 could not be performed. *)

(* ==> $Failed *)
```

### Language`MutationFallthrough

`` Language`MutationFallthrough `` seems to tell the system to abort the mutation process and raise the most recent failed result, for instance this total failure:

```
oop`mut3~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete
Language`SetMutationHandler[oop`ob, oop`mut3]
Language`HandleMutation[oop`ob[sym][[1]] = 2]

(* oop`ob::modfl: The modification oop`ob[sym][[1]]=2 could not be performed. *)

(* ==> $Failed *)
```

is transmogrified into this basic failure we'd expect without the mutation system when using `` Language`MutationFallthrough ``:

```
oop`mut3[___] := Language`MutationFallthrough
Language`HandleMutation[oop`ob[sym][[1]] = 2]

(* Set::setps: oop`ob[sym] in the part assignment is not a symbol. *)

(* ==> HoldComplete[2] *)
```

Comment: So can we say that the mutation handling is a general way to handle modifying complex data types *without* actually introducing entirely new data types (i.e. overloading all functions like `AppendTo` to handle the new head)?

Comment: Sort-of. Your mutation handler function will still need to define a way to handle things like `AppendTo`. Rather I'd say it moves the work from `UpValues` to `DownValues` in mutating a data-type, allowing you to escape, e.g., the depth one restriction without sacrificing performance.

Comment: 1) What is the point of `Set[f[s], p]` as opposed to `Set[f[s,p], v]`? in `SetMutationHandler` example. 2) That may be subjective but I find it terrible to read with all those contexts and short names. What do you think about: `ObjectMutation[  part_[Object[s_], spec___] = value_  ] := Set[part[s, spec], value]`, unless I missed the point or you disagree I could edit the post since I'm trying to parse it anyway.

Answer (score 17):

## `` Language`*ExpressionStore ``

This is a hash-map system (without vectorized calls) that stores items without incrementing the [ref count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) allowing them to be garbage collected naturally

Highly useful for various types of caching. First mentioned by Jason B [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42858568#42858568).

### NewExpressionStore

```
Language`NewExpressionStore["name"]
```

Creates a new `ExpressionStore`

### ExpressionStore

A cache that can be accessed via a slightly funky API:

#### put

Attaches a value to an expression and a key:

```
$store["put"[expr, key, value]]
```

#### get

Accesses a value attached to an expression by key

```
$store["get"[expr, key]]
```

#### remove

Removes the values attached to an expression:

```
$store["remove"[expr]]
```

#### listTable

Lists all cached values and their expressions:

```
$store["listTable"[]]
```

### Notes

#### Hashing by explicit identity

This means that two copies of an expression, since they are different objects at the C++ level at which Mathematica is implemented, get hashed and thus stored differently:

```
Module[
 {
  store = Language`NewExpressionStore["random_store"],
  obj1, 
  obj2,
  sym
  },
 obj1 = sym[];
 obj2 = sym[];
 store["put"[obj1, "key", "value"]];
 {store["get"[obj1, "key"]], store["get"[obj2, "key"]]}
 ]

{"value", Null}
```

#### Ref counts preserved

The reference counter for an expression is not incremented by addition to a store. Thus if it is garbage collected it will be removed from the store

```
Module[
 {
  store = Language`NewExpressionStore["random_store"],
  obj,
  sym,
  res
  },
 obj = sym[];
 store["put"[obj, "key", "value"]];
 res = store["get"[obj, "key"]];
 obj =.; (* activate garbage collection *)
 {res, 
  store["get"[obj, "key"]]}
 ]

{"value", Null}
```

#### Edit

As provided by Jason B. [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46897683#46897683) we also have `"getKeys"` and `"containsQ"`. For those searching from the web, the lack of ref-count incrementing here makes this akin to a [weak hash map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154724/when-would-you-use-a-weakhashmap-or-a-weakreference/154771#154771).

Comment: I have added a wrapper around the expression store with a more sensible syntax (in my opinion) here: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/JasonB/WeakCache/ref/WeakHashTable.html

Answer (score 14):

## `` Language`*Definition* ``

> [...] `` Language`ExtendedDefinition `` and `` Language`ExtendedFullDefinition `` are
>   analogous to `Definition` and `FullDefinition` but capture the definition of a
>   symbol in such a way as it can be reproduced in another kernel. [...]

From [groups.google mathematica thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/0hw5IkrdsTU/v2404uYo9GsJ)

### `` Language`ExtendedDefinition ``

#### Usage

- `ExtendedDefinition[ sym ]` generates `` _Language`DefinitionList `` all values associated with `sym`
- The result can be used to load/overwrite kernel state with those values: `` Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[] = Language`DefinitionList[...] ``

#### Options

*See `ExtendedFullDefinition`...*

#### Basic example

```
bar[x_] := x + 2;
foo[x_] := {x + 1, bar[x]};

temp = Language`ExtendedDefinition[foo]

(* Language`DefinitionList[
     HoldForm[foo] -> {
       OwnValues -> {}, SubValues -> {}, UpValues -> {}
     , DownValues -> {HoldPattern[foo[x_]] :> {x + 1, bar[x]}}
     , NValues -> {}, FormatValues -> {}, DefaultValues -> {}
     , Messages -> {}, Attributes -> {}
     }
   ]
 *)

 ClearAll[foo, bar];

 foo[1]
 (* foo[1] *)

 Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[] = temp;
 foo[1]
 (* {2, bar[1]} *)
```

#### Possible issues

- `DefinitionList` values for `sym` will not merge but overwrite existing state so any previous information about `sym` will be lost.

  ```
  ClearAll[foo, bar];

  foo[x_, y_] := x + y;

  foo[1]     (* ==> foo[1] *)
  foo[1, 2]  (* ==> 3 *)

  Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[] = temp;

  foo[1]     (* ==> {2, bar[1]} *)
  foo[1, 2]  (* ==> foo[1,2] *)
  ```

---

### `` `ExtendedFullDefinition ``

#### Usage

Same as `ExtendedDefinition` but recursively gathers all relevant definitions

#### Options

`ExtendedDefinition` has them too but they are more relevant here.

- `"ExcludedContexts"` which context to ignore when gathering definitions

  Very useful, by default it includes all(?) built in paclets and `` System` `` which automatically fixes a problem of accidentally saving information about `$MachineId` and friends: [Not FullDefinition for Save. MachineID not Protected?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31205/5478)

  ```
  Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[$MachineID] 
    (*Language`DefinitionList[]*)

  Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[$MachineID, "ExcludedContexts" -> {}]
    (*Language`DefinitionList[ stuff...]*)
  ```
- `"IssueReadProtectedMessages"`

  By default `False` but when toggled it can help catch possible problems:

  ```
  SetAttributes[foo, ReadProtected];
  Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[foo, "IssueReadProtectedMessages" -> True]

  (* Language`ExtendedFullDefinition::rpsym :  Symbol foo is ReadProtected.*)
  (* Language`DefinitionList[] *)
  ```

#### Basic example

```
bar[x_] := x + 2;
foo[x_] := {x + 1, bar[x]}

temp = Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[foo]

(* Language`DefinitionList[
     HoldForm[foo] -> {
       OwnValues -> {}, SubValues -> {}, UpValues -> {}
     , DownValues -> {HoldPattern[foo[x_]] :> {x + 1, bar[x]}}
     , NValues -> {}, FormatValues -> {}, DefaultValues -> {}
     , Messages -> {}, Attributes -> {}
     }
   , HoldForm[bar] -> {
       OwnValues -> {}, SubValues -> {}, UpValues -> {}
     , DownValues -> {HoldPattern[bar[x_]] :> x + 2}
     , NValues -> {}, FormatValues -> {}, DefaultValues -> {}
     , Messages -> {}, Attributes -> {}
     }
   ]
*)
```

---

### `` `DefinitionList ``

As far as I know it is just a symbolic wrapper returned and used by `Extended*Definition` functions.

---

### Further reading:

- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=ExtendedFullDefinition

Comment: I see a way to solve this old problem of [automatic deployment of code and dependent functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2625/89) for clean and simple distribution.

Comment: @IstvánZachar yes but in majority of cases i prefer to inject raw source packages as their setup may be environment dependent.

Comment: @IstvánZachar and this is still undocumented :)

Comment: You are of course right Kuba, but my main problem with packages is that my functions are distributed in various packages and deploying **all** related packages would mean a lot of unnecessary data and function-exposition, increasing clatter within the namespace and within the head of users. Well, to be honest, I haven't shared much code recently, so it is no big issue for me.

Comment: You are right too, it depends what fits your workflow best. I just happen to need to produce standalone .cdfs where users don't use functions manually anyway.