# Language`ExpressionStore and ParallelMap

Tags: evaluation, parallelization, undocumented

Is there a way to access [`NewExpressionStore`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171154/38205) from within a parallelized calculation? I have tried variations of

```
Module[{x = "a", s = Language`NewExpressionStore["store"]}, 
 s["put"[x, "value", 1]]; SetSharedVariable[s]; 
 ParallelMap[Print[s["get"[#, "value"]]] &, {x, x}];]

(*
Language`ExpressionStore::nostore :  -- Message text not found -- (Language`ExpressionStore[store])
Language`ExpressionStore::nostore :  -- Message text not found -- (Language`ExpressionStore[store])
Null
Null
*)
```

The sequential equivalent prints two `1` as expected.

```
Module[{x = "a", s = Language`NewExpressionStore["store"]}, 
 s["put"[x, "value", 1]]; Map[Print[s["get"[#, "value"]]] &, {x, x}];]
(*
1
1
*)
```

Comment: In case you don't get a workaround for this, you can use an `Association` or  [`HashTable`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1029/9490) for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work, anything placed in an expression store would only be available on that particular kernel.