# Custom Property interface on my own objects

Tags: customization, undocumented, properties

I know I can use the [`Property` interface](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Properties.html) for things like [`Graph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html) but I want to use it for all of my objects. This includes:

- [`SetProperty`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetProperty.html)
- [`PropertyValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PropertyValue.html)
- [`PropertyList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PropertyList.html)
- [`RemoveProperty`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RemoveProperty.html)

Can I define it in some *efficient*, *non-memory-leaky* way for any object I want?

Answer (score 7):

The answer is a definitive yes, if you're willing to work with the new [`` Language`ExpressionStore ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171154/38205). This goes hand-in-hand with the  [`` Language`MutationHandler ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/165910/38205) stuff to allow us to finally do custom OOP in Mathematica without any odd tricks.

*if you just want to play with this scroll down to the example section*

#### Basic Idea

But for the problem at hand, this is actually very simple. We simply make property-store:

```
$propStore=Language`NewExpressionStore["<PropertyStore>"];
```

Then we use the get-put-remove interface on this:

```
containsQ[x_]:=
  $propStore@"containsQ"[x];
containsQ[x_, p_]:=
  $propStore@"containsQ"[x, p];
(* ::Subsubsection::Closed:: *)
(*get*)
get[x_, p_]:=
  $propStore@"get"[x, p];
(* ::Subsubsection::Closed:: *)
(*set*)
set[x_, p_, v_]:=
  $propStore@"put"[x, p ,v];
(* ::Subsubsection::Closed:: *)
(*remove*)
remove[x_]:=
  $propStore@"remove"[x];
(* ::Subsubsection::Closed:: *)
(*keys*)
keys[]:=
  $propStore@"getKeys"[];
keys[x_]:=
  $propStore@"getKeys"[x];
(* ::Subsubsection::Closed:: *)
(*list*)
list[]:=
  $propStore@"listTable"[];
```

And now we can use this naturally as a property set/get mechanism.

#### Fun Example

I put this all into [a little package](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/raw/master/Props.m) that imitates the syntax of `Property` and friends. Load this from GitHub:

```
Get["https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/raw/master/Props.m"]
```

then we'll define a function that caches results in a memory cheap way:

```
cachedCompute[m_, p_, fn_] :=
 Replace[PropVal[m, p], 
  Missing["PropertyAbsent", p] :>
   With[{val = fn[m]}, 
    SetProp[m, p -> val];
    val
    ]
  ]

Module[{},
  (* I  do this to avoid $HistoryLength *)
  m1 = MemoryInUse[];
  myMat = RandomReal[{}, {100, 100}];
  m1
  ];

t1 = RepeatedTiming[cachedCompute[myMat, "Inverse", Inverse]][[1]];
t2 = RepeatedTiming[Inverse[myMat]][[1]];
m2 = MemoryInUse[];

t2/t1

5.*10^1

m2 - m1

167088

Clear@myMat

MemoryInUse[] - m1

10480
```

And we see the caching got us a 50x speed-up but once the original matrix was cleared, the cached memory was free.

Fast properties without memory leaks, thanks to Jason B.

#### Direct Overloading

We can also make use of this to do some direct overloading for our own type, e.g.:

```
myObj /: PropertyValue[obj_myObj, key_] :=
  PropVal[obj, key];
myObj /: SetProperty[obj_myObj, p : (Rule | RuleDelayed)[key_, val_]] :=

  SetProp[obj, p];
myObj /: RemoveProperty[obj_myObj, key_] :=
  RemoveProp[obj, key];
myObj /: PropertyList[obj_myObj] :=
  PropList[obj];
```

Now it's pretty easy to work with:

```
o = myObj[];

PropertyValue[o, "test"]

Missing["PropertyAbsent", "test"]

SetProperty[o, "test" :> RandomReal[]]

PropertyValue[o, "test"]

0.131471

PropertyValue[o, "test"]

0.882595

RemoveProperty[o, "test"]

Props`Private`$$hold[RandomReal[]] (* just a byproduct of how Hold-ing is done in the package *)
```

Note that this is happening on the `Expression` itself and not the `Symbol`:

```
With[{o = o},
 SetProperty[o, "test" :> RandomReal[]];
 PropertyValue[o, "test"]
 ]

0.170485
```