# Can I overload Part for specific heads (a la overloaded array subscripting)?

Tags: core-language, index, indexed-variable

Mathematica/Wolfram Language newbie here.

The behavior I am after is to be able to "overload" the subscripting of me-defined objects/Heads and thereby use them as if they were `List`s.

Example:  I have a `Blah`, called `b`.  I want to be able to `b[[2]]` and have that call a function that I have defined "on" `b` with parameter `2`, so that I can have custom code return the 2nd part (and likewise for other valid `Part` specifications, i.e. `b[[2;;5]]`...).

The "obvious" (to me) thing to try is e.g.:

```
Part[b_Blah, n_] := ...
```

but this complains that `b` isn't a symbol - apparently rather than adding a new rule to the evaluation engine that matches on `Part[b_Blah, n_]`, the system is trying to evaluate `b[[n]]` and then assign to it (which it cannot, because in this case `b` has no value and thus the expression is not an assignable symbol).

Apologies if I haven't used the right terminology, but my intention here is to "override subscripting" so that I can e.g. lazy-load subscripted/`Part'`d expressions for new objects that I create.  (To simulate memory-mapping on an array/list, for example.)

*Update:  See also "[part 2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235391/how-do-i-get-built-in-functions-to-use-custom-objects-as-if-they-were-e-g-list)", a follow-on to this line of thinking....*

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't understand exactly what you want to do, but can you not use `b[n_] :=... `?

Comment: The other way I can think of is with `TagSet` or whatever it is called. That way, the definition is attached to `Blah` and not to `Part`.

Comment: I suggest that you take a look at `Association[ ]`.

Comment: You can use `Blah` as a head and `Part` will act on `Blah` the same as `Part` does on `List`.  For example, define `b = Blah["first", f[2], "third"];` then evaluate `b[[2]]`.  You get `f[2]`, or whatever you put in the second position.  When you evaluate `Head @ b`, you find that `b` is a `Blah`.  You can also define `b = Blah[ Null, f[2] ]` .  If you edit your question and include a bit more detail or specific examples of what it is you are trying to do, you will be more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: See also [this question/answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165843/language-documentation-project/165910#165910) on ``Language`MutationHandler`` for more advanced custom "objects"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well one can 'overload' system functions of Mathematica using `UpValues` for user-defined symbols like the abstract symbol `array` in the following:

```
ClearAll[array];
array/:Part[a_array,i_Integer]:=arrayGetPart[a,i]
array/:Part[a_array,ij_Span]:=arrayGetSpan[a,ij]
```

which for

```
array[{1, 2, 3}]
%[[1]]
%%[[1 ;; 2]]
```

results in calls to the currently undefined getters

```
array[{1, 2, 3}]
arrayGetPart[array[{1, 2, 3}], 1]
arrayGetSpan[array[{1, 2, 3}], 1 ;; 2]
```

The user-defined `UpValues` supersede the default behavior of `Part` on composite/user-defined objects, which can be disadvantageous in certain scenarios. The overloads or the getters should be further specified to avoid index out of range problems or implement stuff like `[[-1]]`, missing implementations or interpretations for complicated Spans (e.g. m;;n;;l) or multi index versions of `Part` like `[[All,1]]`. I would suggest using very specific overloads (`i_Integer/;0<i<LenghtOfArray[a]`) or getters with rigorous checks on their input parameters to avoid bugs. Stuff like `array/:Part[a_array, 0]:=array` would also be a good idea to restore some of the default functionality of `Part`. After all the specific `UpValues` a plain `UpValue` like `array/:Part[a_array, i_]:=...` could be added either throwing some abort/error message or calling an undefined function to avoid undefined/unintended behavior.

Depending on what exactly OP intends to do, this approach might not be the best code solution in Mathematica but it is closed to the requested 'overloading' behavior. I have used similar constructs/'overloads' to construct data structures and wrappers in Mathematica. Following up on the comment of Jagra under OPs question I would also suggest using `Association` once the data object has an involved internal structure. Something along the lines `array[<|"data"->{...}, "length"->n, "rowMajorQ"->True, ...|>]` would come to mind. With this internal structure an overload like

```
ClearAll[array]
array /: Part[array[asoc_Association], i_] := Part[asoc["data"], i]
```

might be an attractive and highly flexible solution since the data stored in the `Association` can be extended and has named `Keys`. One caveat of the `UpValue` here would be the limitation of the access on the data-values only.

```
ClearAll[array]
array /: Part[array[asoc_Association], i_] := Part[asoc, i]
```

would be a more general approach allowing for things like `array[<|...|>][["data"]][[1]]` and also `array[<|...|>][["rowMajorQ"]]` which eliminates the need for all the trivial getters and is nice and verbose (given one uses good names for his keys).

Comment: `UpValues` get me what I need (a feature I hadn't yet learned about) in terms of directly subscripting the object.  Thanks @n0va!