# How do I get built-in functions to use custom objects as if they were e.g. List?

Tags: core-language

*(This is part 2 of my earlier question, [Can I overload Part for specific heads (a la overloaded array subscripting)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235214/can-i-overload-part-for-specific-heads-a-la-overloaded-array-subscripting), which was well-answered as asked.)*

### Overview:

My goal is to create a custom object - with the basic behavior of a `List`, for example - that lazy-loads its data which might be much larger than physical memory, or distributed across many machines, or computed on need as part of a view, etc.  (This is very loosely analogous to an `mmap`'d file in e.g. C, or perhaps even to a `SparseArray`.)  These objects will, in turn, be used as basic building blocks to construct a ~column-store database (think "a Wolfram Language implementation of ~[kdb+](https://code.kx.com/q/)").

In terms of "direct invocation" of code (i.e., I type the code in the front end), `UpValues` get me what I want to see.  Now the question is:

How can I get built-in functions to recognize/use these objects?

Here's what I have so far (which successfully uses `UpValues` to get me the `Part` behavior I want):

```
In[1]:= array /: Part[b_array, i_Integer] := arrayGetPart[b, i]

In[2]:= array /: Part[array[assoc_Association], s_String] := 
 Part[assoc[s]]

In[3]:= arrayGetPart[a_array, i_Integer] := 
 If[1 <= i <= a[["maxLength"]], i, Missing[]]

In[4]:= a = 
 array[<|"file" -> "a-really-big-column-file", "maxLength" -> 1000000000000|>]

Out[4]= array[<|"file" -> "a-really-big-column-file", "maxLength" -> 1000000000000|>]

In[5]:= a[["file"]]

Out[5]= "a-really-big-column-file"

In[6]:= {a[[-1]], a[[1]], a[[1001]], a[[1000000000000]], 
 a[[1000000000001]]}

Out[6]= {Missing[], 1, 1001, 1000000000000, Missing[]}
```

So far, so good!  But what about our friend `Mean`?

```
In[7]:= Mean[a]

Out[7]= Mean[
 array[<|"file" -> "a-really-big-column-file", "maxLength" -> 1000000000000|>]]
```

Minimally it seems I would need to implement e.g. `Length[a_array]` and other "fundamental accessors"....

If that's a correct approach for `Mean` (where it is spelled out in the documentation that `Mean[list]` is equivalent to `Total[list]/Length[list]`), what about for other built-in Wolfram Language functions?  How, in general, can I learn what primitive accessors I will need to implement, and how do I then inject those rules into the system?

### Random remarks:

I am vaguely aware of (but have not used) MathLink, but it would be *very much preferred* to have a pure Wolfram Language implementation, even if that means some sacrifice in performance.

I have also played with the `RelationalDatabase` functionality, and this is broadly the direction I am heading, what with its style of "in-language" queries (albeit modeled around `EntityStore`).  Alas, `RelationalDatabase` has abysmal performance and is closed in the sense of being able to add new operators to its own query language (which are then translated into ~SQL queries against the underlying database).

What I also want to avoid is having to reimplement every function that I might want to use in a query against the database - that is obviously possible, but it defeats the point of using a rich language such as Wolfram Language, and it would create a shadow/pidgin language that no one including myself would want to use.  So, ideally, I'd like to get away with "a few" underlying primitive operations to do with e.g. `List` access....

Comment: Since you talked about lazy lists, there are a couple of implementations of those that could save you some work or, if nothing else, the would show you exactly how to go about “overloading” existing functions to work with custom objects. See [Sjoerd Smit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/43522/sjoerd-smit)’s [Lazy Lists package](https://github.com/ssmit1986/lazyLists), and [Leonid Shifrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin)’s [implementation based on ``Streaming` ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85336/27951)

Comment: Hrm.  Smit seems to have [manually implemented](https://github.com/ssmit1986/lazyLists/blob/main/lazyLists/Kernel/lazySyntacticSugar.wl) all the functions that interact with the lazy lists.  And Shifrin's approach uses undocumented features.

Comment: Yes. I was hoping that Sjoerd's approach could serve as a guide to implementing your own object.

Comment: Thank you!  However, the more I get into this, the more I suspect that what I want to achieve is not, in general, possible.  It seems the sort of polymorphism I am after is possible if all the code were "in userland" (not locked, not compiled, and not a built-in primitive) and already written in terms of extensible interfaces/supertypes/whatever, but not otherwise; for example, to implement `Part` and `Length` on a new type of `List`, and get operations that are logically computable from those (such as `Mean`, `Variance`, and `StandardDeviation`) "for free".