# Make matrixes with numbered name

Tags: matrix, variable, string-manipulation

Suppose I have two matrixes

```
 M1 = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
 M2 = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
```

Now I wanna have $N$ matrixes in this form called M1, M2, M3, M4,...MN

How to code to make $N$ matrixes with the name Mn?

***I would like to avoid using an indexed variable approach***

Comment: May I ask about the reasons for your requirement of " avoid using an indexed variable approach". What about working with rank-3 tensors?

Comment: Is there anything you can do with named variables that you can't do with the rank-3 approach?

Comment: There is also `Table["M" <> IntegerString[i, 10, 2], {i, 1, 16}]`, giving {M01, M02, M03, M04, M05, M06, M07, M08, M09, M10, M11, M12, M13, M14, M15, M16}, or (if you prefer hexadecimal!) `Table["M" <> IntegerString[i, 16, 2], {i, 1, 16}]` giving {M01, M02, M03, M04, M05, M06, M07, M08, M09, M0a, M0b, M0c, M0d, M0e, M0f, M10} or maybe [on a scale of 1 to 10](https://xkcd.com/953/)  `Table["M" <> IntegerString[i, 2, 8], {i, 1, 10}]` giving {M00000001, M00000010, M00000011, M00000100, M00000101, M00000110, M00000111, M00001000, M00001001, M00001010} :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ToString` and `ToExpression` to form the variable names and make assignments to them.

Variable names:

```
varNames = Table["M" <> ToString[i], {i, 12}]

(* {"M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7", "M8", "M9", "M10", "M11", "M12"} *)
```

Clear variables:

```
Clear /@ varNames;
```

Assign matrices:

```
Do[Evaluate[ToExpression[m]] = RandomReal[10, {2, 2}], {m, varNames}]
```

Get a matrix:

```
M3

(* {{7.16959, 8.2422}, {6.35256, 9.84186}} *)
```

Get another matrix:

````
M10

(* {{7.0324, 7.755}, {0.0542816, 4.98438}} *)
```
````

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"];
```

Use an indexed variable `m[n]` rather than `mn`

```
Format[a[n_]] := Subscript[a, n]

m[n_Integer?Positive] := Array[a[n][##] &, {2, 2}]

Column[MatrixForm[m[#]] & /@ Range[3]]
```

[image]

```
m[20] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Re your comment below, since `a1` is **not** a matrix. `a[1][[1, 1]]` is not the correct syntax. Use

```
a[1][1, 1] = 1;
```

then when `m[1]` is generated

```
m[1]
```

[image]

Since `m[1]` is a matrix, to replace `m[1][[1,1]]`

```
ReplacePart[m[1], {1, 1} -> 2]
```

[image]

Or first store `m[1]`

```
mat = m[1]
```

[image]

and make a replacement in the stored copy

```
mat[[1, 1]] = 2;

mat
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Using indexed variable approach, how to avoid assignment problems? For example a[1][[1, 1]] = 1 gives the error Set::setps: Subscript[a, 1] in the part assignment is not a symbol.

Comment: @Nigel1 See [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/249706/36508) for some approaches on how to deal with that

Answer (score 2):

There are of course many ways to do this, but often the approach of creating a 3D array is the most systematic

```
M1 = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
M2 = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};

M = {M1, M2};
```

You can access whole arrays

```
M[[2]]
(* {{0, 0}, {0, 0}} *)
```

and update individual elements

```
M[[1]][[2, 2]] = 7;

M[[1]]
(* {{0, 0}, {0, 7}} *)
```