# How to clear this variable

Tags: variable, clear

[image]

I can not clear this variable.
How to clear?

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/373/clear-complains-that-a-subscripted-variable-is-not-a-symbol-or-a-string or https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128498/how-to-clear-the-downvalues-of-a-subscripted-variable, perhaps.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Clear[Subscript]

Comment: For yet one more complication of this phenomenon in the setting of assigning values to spans of subscripted variables, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249706/assignment-with-span-to-indexed-variable

Answer (score 1):

To clear Mathematica variables that are not symbols you set them equal to .

```
Subscript[\[Sigma], \[Epsilon]] =.
```

This will clear it.

Don't use subscripts.  Mathematica does not not handle them very well and in general they cause nothing but problems.

Comment: Thank you very much!